# How to create a program that automatically clicks on the link in texts I receive from a particular number?

Tags: bots

I am new to python but I am wondering if I can click on the links I get in texts from a particular number. These texts are potential leads for my business and I want to know if I can automatically click on the link from the texts which would secure the lead. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can check my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question is that you get a text , and you wanna get on the links that this text contains

- First you can extract the links from text ( extract the lines starting with "http" and finishing with "com" or "net" ... etc

*for that you can use regular expressions , like the following example :*

```
import re

text = 'https://first.com then this one https://second.com'
liste = re.findall('https(.+?)com',text)
your_list = list()

for e in liste :
    your_list.append('https'+e+'com')

print(your_list)
```

- Then you will store these links as Strings on a list of Strings

*It is the your_list that contains all links*

- For each link on the list , try an http request using a web service client program that will be included on your algorithm , and then get the html or json result depending on the link , and here you can execute the securing task that you want

*Here we can send http request using GET or POST like the following*

*First you'll have to install a package called requests*

```
pip install requests
```

*I will show you as an example a request for an API that will return the gender of the given name*

```
import requests

url = "https://gender-api.com/get?name=elizabeth"
r = requests.get(url=url) # using GET 
data = r.json()
print(data) # returns the json result
```

And here you can make the operation that you want

**Here is a complete example**

```
import re

text = 'This text contains a link that i wanna check it manually 
https://gender-api.com/get?name=elizabeth i dont know' \
   'where is it'
liste = re.findall('https(.+?)elizabeth',text)
your_list = list()

for e in liste :
    your_list.append('https'+e+'elizabeth')

import requests

for url in your_list:
    r = requests.get(url=url)
    data = r.json()
    print(data)
```

*Output*

```
{'name': 'elizabeth', 'errno': 40, 'errmsg': 'invalid or missing key', 'gender': 'unknown', 'samples': 0, 'accuracy': 0, 'duration': '32ms', 'credits_used': 1}
```

Comment: @MohamedKaramThat is the sort of idea I am looking for. I could use the help with the code. Thanks.

Comment: @CameronMoore i will share with you the code as answers

Comment: @CameronMoore you will find it on my previous answer edited